# How do I calculate a loss rate from the reflectivity?

Tags: reflection, laser-cavity

If I have a laser cavity that is contained between two mirrors and I know the reflectivity, R1 and R2, of each mirror, is there an easy way to calculate the photon loss rate through each of the mirrors per second?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, suppose the laser cavity is of length $L$. The round trip time of photon is $\frac{2 L }{c}$. In each round trip, the fractional loss is $1-R_1R_2$.

So loss rate = $\frac{c(1 - R_1R_2)}{2 L}$. This has units of $s^{-1}$.

Comment: This just accounts for reflection looses, but there's [other types of looses](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485146/what-are-the-losses-in-a-laser-cavity) such as optical cavity absorption, diffraction limitations, etc.