# What are the losses in a laser cavity?

Tags: laser, laser-interaction, laser-cavity

I studied that to get the lasing conditions gain must overcome the losses. But what are the losses? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The main ones are:

- Mirror losses. No mirror is 100% reflective. Even if there were, if you used 100% reflective mirrors on both ends, your laser would have no output beam.
- Scattering in the beam path, or material absorption in the beam path.
- Diffraction. The beam spreads as it travels, so there is some light that simply falls outside the area of the mirrors.
- Any light you pick off to monitor the beam strength.

Answer (score 0):

The significant losses in laser comes from

- the reflection loss of the grating (wavelength selective);
- resonance losses between R1 and R2;
- material attenuation and
- nonradiative combinations

Comment: Nonradiateive combinations are an electrical loss mechanism in a laser that limits quantum efficiency and wall-plug efficiency, but when OP asks about the question of the round trip gain exceeding the losses, they're asking about optical losses.